# Android CheckBox setCheck(True)

Tags: android

I wanto do the upload from Android sqlite to sql sever. Its working fine uploading.Problem is : each table upload finish , service return true/false. If it is true then need to `setChecked(true);`. Here i created check box dynamically in one method, i want to set the status from another method....

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View viewInflate = LayoutInflater.from(UploadActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.upload_screen, null);
    setContentView(viewInflate);
    if (uploadTable.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadTable.size(); i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setId(i);
            ch = new CheckBox(this);
            ch.setId(i);
            ch.setChecked(false);
            tr.addView(ch);
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
            createView(tr, tv2, uploadTable.get(i));
            uploadingTable.addView(tr);
        }
    }
  }
```

This is the method calling service..

```
   public boolean soapPrimitiveData(String tablename,String strBusinessUnit, String strExecutive,String jsonString) throws IOException,XmlPullParserException {
    SoapPrimitive responsesData = null;
    boolean status =false;
    SoapObject requestData = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); // set
    requestData.addProperty("strBusinessUnit", strBusinessUnit);
    requestData.addProperty("strExecutiveCode", strExecutive);
    requestData.addProperty("strTableName", tablename);
    requestData.addProperty("jsonContent", jsonString);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopes = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap//// envelope
    envelopes.dotNet = true;
    envelopes.setOutputSoapObject(requestData);
    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(APPURL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelopes);
        responsesData = (SoapPrimitive) envelopes.getResponse();
        if((responsesData.toString()).equals("true")){
            DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(UploadActivity.this);

            status = dbAdapter.updateUploadedTable(tablename, strExecutive, strBusinessUnit);

                 if(status){
                   ch.setChecked(true);
                  }
        }


    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error : " , "Error on soapPrimitiveData() " + e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

This is not checked check box value. How can i take particular checkbox.for example findById() also can't use it.

Layout design like this:

```
    CheckBox  WMInvoice
    CheckBox  WMInvoiceLine
```

Like that.but it create dynamically.

Please help me out from this problem

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `ch.setChecked(true);` is called within an UI Thread, try:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
             ch.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create list that can hold your `CheckBoxes`:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> myCheckBoxes;
```

Instantiate it in `onCreate()` before your `for-loop`:

```
myCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

When you add each `CheckBox` to your `TableRow` (in your `for-loop`) also add it to your list:

```
myCheckBoxes.add( ch );
```

Then you will need some way of identifying which `CheckBox` to check during `soapPrimitiveData`-call. I see that you set the ID of each `CheckBox` so if you could somehow pass an `int` to the `soapPrimitiveData`-method you can check the right `CheckBox` like this:

```
if(status){
   for( CheckBox box : myCheckBoxes )
      if( box.getId() == idPassedToMethod ) {
         ch.setChecked(true);
         break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this help. But it always check last item. It didn't find the specific checkbox.For example if i upload 2nd table then it should check 2nd check box. but it check last one.Please any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting id the same way you pick the container using id

```
ch.getId(i);
```

this will give you the i'th checkbox in your layout